# Get an Exception from CDI transactional observer methods

Tags: java, transactions, cdi

We can declare an observer method as a transactional by defining `TransactionPhase` attribute like:

```
public void onDocumentUpdate(@Observes(during=AFTER_SUCCESS) @Updated Document doc) {
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to get an `Exception` which causes transaction to be broken from within a transactional CDI observers?
For example, I'd like to write some business logic for certain scenario based on an `Exception` thrown:

```
void onDocumentUpdate(@Observes(during=AFTER_FAILURE) @Updated Document doc) {
    Exception e = getFailureCause();
    if (check_wether_e_is_instance_of_ConstraintViolationException) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to achieve it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using CDI interceptors to handle exceptions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I cannot accept your answer because it is rather a workaround for the problem and my question is about whether the transaction-breaking-exception can be generally caught from within observer method. Maybe your solution is a natural "CDI-way" to handle exceptions, but I'd like to get some more informative explanation. Thanks anyway!